# AS3 XML issue with first element

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have this XML problem that is bugging me today, and I can't find a solution because I don't know how to phrase it.
My XML file looks like this:

```
<TEST>
  <ITEM_ID>0123
    <ITEM_SIZE>Medium</ITEM_SIZE>
    <ITEM_COLOR>Red</ITEM_COLOR>
  </ITEM_ID>
</TEST>
```

Everything works fine (i can find a random element, display or erase it) and can get the information I want, but the only thing that I cannot access the  with myXML_XML.ITEM_ID[0], which shoud say "0123". I get nothing, no error, nothing. When I check myXML_XML.ITEM_ID[0].ITEM_SIZE (when put in a String Var, I get "Medium" ).

I thought perhaps the XML was misleading so I tried with another file:

```
<TEST>
      <ITEM_ID REF="0123">
        <ITEM_SIZE>Medium</ITEM_SIZE>
        <ITEM_COLOR>Red</ITEM_COLOR>
      </ITEM_ID>
    </TEST>
```

Which gave me the same results, when checking for myXML_XML.ITEM_ID[0].REF or  myXML_XML.ITEM_ID[0].REF.text

Anyone kind enough to enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first XML schema seems to be a little off, but valid nonetheless. You might want to try children() method of the nodes.

`myXML_XML.ITEM_ID[0].children()[0] // This is the text node`

In the other example, which is more readable in fact, you should use @ sign for accessing attributes

`myXML_XML.ITEM_ID[0].@REF`

Here is a complete example:

```
var test:XML = new XML(
    <foo>
        <bar id="4444">
            efghi
            <baz>1234</baz>
            <quux>6789</quux>
        </bar>
        <bar id="4445">
            zxcv
            <baz>4567</baz>
            <quux>9876</quux>
        </bar>
    </foo>
);

trace(test.bar[0].children()[0]); // efghi
trace(test.bar[1].@id); // 4445
```

Comment: ah thank you ever so much, this was exactly what I was looking for. The reason the XML Schema is a bit weird is that by using this, I can manage to remove a node with: delete myXML_XML.ITEM_ID[0].parent().children() [myXML_XML.ITEM_ID[0].childIndex()}

Comment: but I also needed to record somewhere what I deleted (the ITEM_ID[0]) which I could not access. Thank you a million for making the @ clear to me in your example. Nik